# postgreSQL online shell

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have installed postgreSQL multiple times because I did not know better in the past, and now I am having trouble running SQL shell (psql) on my desktop.

It would not let me log in, would not tell me all the versions that I have installed, would not let me change supervisor user.

However, I really need to find a way to run my SQL commands and output script style result (like the analog format you would get on SQL shell) in order to complete my homework.

I have already checked the results of my commands on pgadmin 4 on my browser, so I just have to run it and get script style output. 
Do any of you know an online SQL shell that I can use?

Thank you.

Comment: try https://www.db-fiddle.com?

Comment: If you can connect with pgAdmin the you can also connect using `psql`